# Why can't my Python server handle data from multiple clients simultaneously using select.select()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, select

I'm trying to make a server that would recieve and unpack struct objects from several clients simultaneously in Python. The program works when only 1 client is connected to the server, but it produces a struct.error when more than 1 client is connected.

It's as if the 2 clients would send their data as one, thus creating an object that is the wrong size for struct.unpack().

Serverside code:

```py
def handleConnections(self):
         while self.inputs:
            try:
                readable, writeable, exceptional = select.select(self.inputs, self.outputs, self.inputs, self.timeout)

                if not (readable or writeable or exceptional):
                    continue

                self.handleInputs(readable, writeable)
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print("Never liked you anyway")
                sys.exit()

def handleInputs(self, readable, writeable):
        for sock in readable:
            if sock is self.server:
                self.handleNewConnection(sock)
            else:
                self.handleQuestionFromClient(sock, writeable)

def handleQuestionFromClient(self, client, writeable):
        question = client.recv(1024)

        self.respondToClient(question, writeable)

def respondToClient(self, question, writeable):
        question = struct.unpack("ci", question)
        print("recieved question: ", question)
        # Do more stuff
```

I would expect each and every client to independently send these struct objects to the server, and in turn the server to independently unpack and work with them.
However when there are 2 or more clients, I get this struct.error resulting for the struct.unpack() method recieving an argument of the wrong size.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Bonus\2019.osz_Telekommunikacios_halozatok\barkoba\server.py", line 104, in <module>
    barkobaServer.handleConnections()
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Bonus\2019.osz_Telekommunikacios_halozatok\barkoba\server.py", line 95, in handleConnections
    self.handleInputs(readable, writeable)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Bonus\2019.osz_Telekommunikacios_halozatok\barkoba\server.py", line 33, in handleInputs
    self.handleQuestionFromClient(sock, writeable)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Bonus\2019.osz_Telekommunikacios_halozatok\barkoba\server.py", line 83, in handleQuestionFromClient
    self.respondToClient(question, writeable)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Bonus\2019.osz_Telekommunikacios_halozatok\barkoba\server.py", line 44, in respondToClient
    question = struct.unpack("ci", question)
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 8 bytes
```

I can't wrap my head around why this code works for a single client but fails when two or more clients are connected simultaneously.

(I'm not sure if the code I've provided is sufficient, this is my first question on StackOverflow)

Answer (score 0):

You execute

> ```
>     question = client.recv(1024)
> ```

and then assume that eight bytes arrived which you can `unpack()`.

A bit of debugging would soon reveal that,
across your two connections,
one receives one or more bytes and the other receives zero bytes.

Unpacking zero bytes will make you sad. Test for length less than eight.